# Nazgul: The WitchKing of Angmar & the other 8 - roots?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

> "They were once Men. Great Kings of Men. Then Sauron the Deciever gave
>   them Nine Rings of Power. Blinded by their greed, they took them
>   without question, one by one, falling into darkness. And now they are
>   slaves to his will. They are the Nazgûl, Ringwraiths, neither living
>   nor dead. At all times, they feel the presence of the Ring, drawn to
>   the power of the One. They will never stop hunting you." 
>   - Aragorn, explaining the Nazgûl's origin to Frodo, Sam, Pippin and Merry
>
> "Nine he gave to Mortal Men, proud and great, and so ensnared them.
>   Long ago they fell under the domination of the One, and they became
>   Ringwraiths, shadows under his great Shadow, his most terrible
>   servants." 
>   - Gandalf, to Frodo (The Lord of the Rings, The Fellowship of the Ring, Chapter 2, "The Shadow of the Past")
>
> "Once nine great Kings of Men, they were all given Rings of Power. The
>   Nine took them without question and subsequently, after the forging of
>   the One Ring, became slaves of Sauron and later his chief lieutenants.
>   After centuries the effect of the rings left the kings spectral,
>   invisible to all but Sauron and whoever wore the One Ring."
>   - http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Nazg%C3%BBl

This is all i can find about their biography regarding their beginnings, during their changing and the beginning of their changing.

**Is there anyone able to direct me to some info about them before receving the rings?**
Kings of men - where, when, etc.? Or there is no such info? It would be a surprise for me to see that there is no details about them before receving the ring, since Tolkien didn't miss any character to develop a full path from birth / appearance till death / destruction.

Comment: Some sources will give names and background info for all 9, but those originate from the MERP game and not from Tolkien's own writings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only one about whom more details are available is their leader, Witch-King of Angmar.

A good (and as is typical of that site, well-sourced) compilation of that info is Tolkien Gateway: http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Witch-king

A bit is known about one more: his name (Khamûl) and that he was [a king of Easterlings](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Kham%C3%BBl).

Comment: The Akallabeth also notes "*it is said that among those whom he ensnared with the Nine Rings three were great lords of Numenorean race*".

Comment: @JimmyShelter - that's worth an answer